# How to place a catagory between two ranges?

Tags: excel, range, categorical-data

im looking to place a category based off two numbers and two ranges. For example i have my isotope data

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJVvE.png)

from this data i want to determine the pollution source based on these two ranges
[image]

eg the inputs are the isotope data 15N and 18O and the output is source or in some cases multiple sources if ranges overlap.

so for example if 15N is 4 and 18O is 22 then the source is Nitrate Fertilizer

Sorry if my explanation is confusing!

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of what the output should be given that input?

Comment: Your examples don't seem to tie well to the image you provided. It's also unclear from your photo what the input is and what the output is? Will need to elaborate more on what needs to be done here. *Given these inputs I need to get to this output by using this logic*

Comment: Why couldn't it be nitrate precipitation?

Comment: @SJR - that is a good point. OP: These ranges overlap. Should the first "match" be returned?

Comment: Yes, the output should be pollution source which is shown in the table and the inputs are the 15N and 18N data, i have now updated a picture. Yes the ranges can overlap and if they do then both would be the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$9;AGGREGATE(15;6;((ROW($A$3:$A$9)-ROW($A$2))/(($I3>=$B$3:$B$9)*($I3<=$C$3:$C$9)*($J3>=$D$3:$D$9)*($J3<=$E$3:$E$9)));COLUMNS($K$1:K$1)));"")}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Replace semicolons with comma if needed.

If more than three sources are possible, the formula should be copied further to the right

[image]

Comment: Thank you! i was just using a column for each source then using an IF formula but  this is much more clean!